# How can I receive a DefaultFileRegion?

Tags: file, netty

The netty project explained how to use the FileRegion to accomplish the zero-copy file transfer in [FileServerHandler example](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/file/FileServerHandler.java), but I never find out how should I receive them in channelRead? I don't know how to read the DefaultFileRegion contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileRegion sends the bytes of the file in the specified offset-length region. so from the receiver perspective it's basically like sending a ByteBuf.

to better understand what you receiving, you can simply take the EchoServer example, and instead of writing back what you are receiving you can print it on the screen.

Comment: It's hard to distinguish bytebuf from other useful information, I guess the FileRegion is not a good API for that. Transferring file on internet always needs some more information to describe it, which FileRegion doesn't provide.

Comment: you should think at FileRegion as a helper that does "open(file) + seek(offset) + read(buf) + close(file) + send(buf)" in an efficient way nothing more. the FileRegion is a "low level" object. On top of that you have to buid a protocol. and at that level you can add all the information you want which file was transfered which offset-length is the piece of file and so on.